# Footable data json

Tags: javascript, php, json, footable

I have a footable that i want to supply with json data.

I know (well i think i know how to) how to fill the array, but i use some php where i get my data with an echo json_encode.

When i console.log the response. that give me :

```
[{"idsecteur":"1","nomsecteur":"Abat jour","type":"int"},{"idsecteur":"17","nomsecteur":"A\u00e9ronautique","type":"int"}]
```

When i copy/paste that code in :

```
$('.tableUsersSecteur').footable({"columns": mycolumns, "rows": [{"idsecteur":"1","nomsecteur":"Abat jour","type":"int"},{"idsecteur":"17","nomsecteur":"A\u00e9ronautique","type":"int"}]});
```

that work but when i just put the response

```
$('.tableUsersSecteur').footable({"columns": columns, "rows": row});
```

that doesn't work... If anyone has an idea?

Thankful for your answers.

EDIT :

My code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ps/manageuser.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            row = response.row ;
            column = response.columns;

            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScript.src = '../js/footable.js';
            newScript.onload = function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log(row);
            console.log(column);                
                $('.tableUsersSecteur').footable({"columns": column, "rows": row});
                });
            };
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            head.appendChild(newScript);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should show the part where you request the data, where `row` is set, and where your `.footable(` call is placed.

Comment: @t.niese thanks, edited

Comment: And the `console.log` shows the correct content? Did you check if the `onload` and the `.ready(` callbacks are called.

Comment: The console.log(row) show exactly what i copy paste (that's what i've copied before) and yes the onload and the .ready are good, (else i could'nt had the good things with a copy paste if they where not called)

Comment: I can bring some screen shots if that can help you

Comment: The `console.log` of `row` and `column` are in in the `success` callback in the shown code. So they would be logged even if the `onload` of the `newScript` is not executed. So place a `console.log` in both the `onload` and the `ready` (update the code in the question accordingly) and tell what is logged.

Comment: I juste put the `console.log` on the line before my `.footable` and that console me exactly the same that before

Answer (score 0):

Like i find my own answer, i'll give it to you too ! 
To give an array of object in footable u should to add in the html : `data-type="object"` on the `<table>` tag